# Problem with Java Scanner when using NetBeans, it does not show any reaction

Tags: java, netbeans

I recently started to learn Java language. But I have to use NetBeans for some reasons. Problem is that every time I use Scanner to get input from user it does not show any reaction and only the DING sound comes from computer speaker. I tried almost all of the solutions available in internet but problem still exists.
Environmental variables and settings of netbeans also look right. Note that those codes run perfectly when I use Intellij IDEA or windows cmd. Does anyone Know how to fix this problem? For example netbeans has problem even with this simple code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class CircleArea{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double radius;
        System.out.println("\nEnter radius of circle in cm:");
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
        radius = myObj.nextDouble();  // Read user input
        System.out.println("Calculated area of the circle in cm2 is :"+area(radius));
    }
    static double area(double r){
        return 3.14*r*r;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code works correctly for me (I am using NetBeans 12). After launching the program, click your cursor anywhere in the "Output - Run" window. Then type in a radius value and hit Enter. For example, I entered `12` and the output was given as: `Calculated area of the circle in cm2 is :452.15999999999997`.

Comment: I also tried this one. But it didn't work. Just like you my netbeans is version 12.

Comment: Problem finally solved with netbeans11 and jdk11